# How to stop all the process when opening a new form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms

I have a button in a main form that open another form
when I open it I don't want other code after the open form code to run until I close the form2
for example:

```
Form2.Show();
Messagebox.show("text");
```

I don't want to display the message box until the form 2 is closed

Comment: Use `Form2.ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Form.Show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=netframework-4.8) shows the form as a modeless windows. This causes the execution to continue to the next statements (i.e. the method `Show` immediatly returns).

On the other hand [`Form.ShowDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.8) shows the form as a [**modal window**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window). In addition to blocking the UI, it also does not return from the `ShowDialog` method until the form is closed.

Therefore you should change:

```
Form2.Show();
```

To:

```
Form2.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simple do something like this, use [ShowDialog()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). `Show` method displays the form in a non-modal way. `showdialog` displays the form in a modal way

```
Form2.ShowDialog();
Messagebox.show("text");
```